# numpy random choice and lists of networkx Graphs

Tags: python, numpy, random, networkx

So, I want to do some reproducible stochastic simulations that I can share with others, for which I need to create a random state in numpy, using `RS = np.random.RandomState(seed)`.  So far so good.

But in my case, I may want to be able to choose a graph from a list.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

G = nx.Graph()
L = [G]
np.random.choice(L)
> mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.choice()
> ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

This works with `random` (as opposed to `np.random`), but I see suggestions that `random` may not give consistent results across different systems, even with the same seed.

Is there anything I can do to get numpy's random choice to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `index` `random` then pick the value by its `index`

```
L[np.random.choice(np.array(len(L)),1)[0]]
```